# GCS folder name search pattern to get the list of blob using python API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have daily file available in GCS bucket in the following pattern and I need to get those blobs for further process.

```
gs://bucket_name/202112032210/test/a.csv
gs://bucket_name/202112042310/test/b.csv
gs://bucket_name/202112052240/test/a1.csv
```

So folder name would be : yyyymmdd and then time. Time could be anything and I need to go by each day folder. I am trying to check the file availability for each day using the following pattern but it didn't work :

```
timestr = str(today.strftime('%Y')) +  str(today.strftime('%m')) + str(today.strftime('%d'))
FOLDER_NAME=timestr +'*'+'/test/'
storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket()
    for blob in storage_client.list_blobs(prefix=FOLDER_NAME):
            num = blob.name.count('/')
            file_name = blob.name.split('/')[num].strip('.csv')
            blob = bucket.blob(blob.name)
            print(blob)
```

But I am not getting the the blobs. Please suggest any workaround for the same to get the folder for each day.

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: I am not getting the blob using  /20211203*/temp/ .. so I need approach to look into 202112032210/test/

Comment: The prefix does not support wildcards AFAIK. Use a prefix of **yyyymm**. That will return all objects that start with **yyyymm**. Remember, Cloud Storage does not have folders/directories. The namespace is flat.

Comment: Please, consider read [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379101/how-to-get-list-blobs-to-behave-like-gsutil): it doesn't answer yours, but I think it may be of help.